# How do I subclass this class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, subclass

I know 'class' is not proper term for javascript sometimes.

There is a this library ([dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)) which I want to modify without altering the original file.

The Dropzone class is defined like below, (I included parts which looks relavant)

```
// Uses AMD or browser globals to create a jQuery plugin.
(Function (factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
      // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
      define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else {
      // Browser globals
      factory(jQuery);
  }
} (function (jQuery) {
    var module = { exports: { } }; // Fake component

/**
 * Expose `Emitter`.
 */

module.exports = Emitter;


(function() {
  var Dropzone, Em, camelize, contentLoaded, detectVerticalSquash, drawImageIOSFix, noop, without,
    __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
    __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.protot\
ype; return child; },
    __slice = [].slice;

  Em = typeof Emitter !== "undefined" && Emitter !== null ? Emitter : require("emitter");

  noop = function() {};

  Dropzone = (function(_super) {
    var extend;

    __extends(Dropzone, _super);
  })(Em);

}).call(this);

    return module.exports;
}));
```

How would I go about creating a 'CustomDropzone' so that I can override some of Dropzone.prototype.foo funcitons?